# Using a decorator in a python class, undefined variables

Tags: python, function, discord.py

I have a function that runs a decorator, but I need the `async def _test` to run from inside the class.

```py
class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Slash(bot))
    bot.slash = SlashCommand(bot, override_type=True, sync_commands=True)

    @bot.slash.slash(name="test")
    async def _test(ctx: SlashContext, a=None, b=None):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="embed test")
        await ctx.send(content="test", embeds=[embed])
```

`bot` is not defined if I just move the code inside the class, and `self.` can't be used in the decorator. Any idea how I can get the function to be in the class? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `cog_ext.cog_slash` decorator

```py
from discord_slash import cog_ext

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="test")
    async def _test(self, ctx: SlashContext, a=None, b=None):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="embed test")
        await ctx.send(content="test", embeds=[embed])
```

*PS: It's in the introduction, I haven't even looked at the docs, only at the PyPi page... I don't know how you could've missed it*

Comment: late reply but still - I tried using the cog_ext from the docs, but it never worked. The other example outside of a cog works fine, but the cog ext doesn't